# Shouldn’t the Zener diode be not in active state here?

Tags: diodes

I thought the Zener diode (break down voltage = 6V) will not be active here. That is it will not start acting as voltage regulator here since potential difference across 4 kΩ is 4 V if not in connected with diode in parallel. So after connecting in parallel it should still not be acting as 6 V, it will remain 4 V and current flowing through circuit will be 10/1000 = 0.01 A.

[image]0.01A?

(Answer given was using active state (10 - 6) V / 6 kΩ = 0.667 mA.)

Comment: Welcome! I tried to clear up your question but please edit _”10-6/6K\ohm”_ and clarify it.

Comment: Edited thanks. ..

Comment: For all future reference, it’s kohm or kΩ, not “K\ohm”.

Comment: Sure okay winny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct except for

> ... and current flowing through circuit will be 10/1000 = 0.01 A.

The resistance is 10 kΩ so \$ I = \frac {10}{10k} = 1 \ \text{mA}\$.